# Python IBM Watson NLU Sentiment Analysis - TypeError: cannot convert dic

Tags: python, typeerror, ibm-watson

Using the following code, I get the error message

> TypeError: cannot convert dictionary update sequence element #0 to a sequence

The code used is he following:

```
import watson_developer_cloud as WDC
import watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.features.v1 as nluFeatures
#from wdc_config import nlu_config

nlu = WDC.NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1('2017-02-27',username='myusernamehere',password='mypasswordhere')

data = ([1, "I've seen things you people wouldn't believe. Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion. I watched C-beams glitter in the dark near the Tannhauser Gate. All those moments will be lost in time, like tears in rain. Time to die."])


def nlu_analyze():
    response = nlu.analyze(text=data,features=[nluFeatures.Keywords(),nluFeatures.Entities(),nluFeatures.Categories(),nluFeatures.Emotion(),nluFeatures.Sentiment()])
    return response

response = nlu_analyze()
print(response["keywords"])
print(response["entities"])
print(response["categories"])
print(response["emotion"])
print(response["sentiment"])
```

Why do I get this error?

---

## Solved

Thanks to chughts this problem is solved.

```
import watson_developer_cloud as WDC
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, KeywordsOptions, EntitiesOptions, CategoriesOptions, EmotionOptions, SentimentOptions


nlu = WDC.NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1('2017-02-27',username='yourusername',password='yourpassword')

data = ("I've seen things you people wouldn't believe. Attack ships on fire off the shoulder of Orion. I watched C-beams glitter in the dark near the Tannhauser Gate. All those moments will be lost in time, like tears in rain. Time to die.")

def nlu_analyze():
    response = nlu.analyze(text=data, features=Features(keywords=KeywordsOptions(), entities=EntitiesOptions(), categories=CategoriesOptions(), emotion=EmotionOptions(), sentiment=SentimentOptions()))

return response

response = nlu_analyze()
print(response["keywords"])
print(response["entities"])
print(response["categories"])
print(response["emotion"])
print(response["sentiment"])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies in your import of the features

```
import watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding.features.v1 as nluFeatures
```

which according to the API documentation - https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/natural-language-understanding/api/v1/?python#post-analyze
should be

```
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 \
  import Features, KeywordsOptions, EntitiesOptions, CategoriesOptions, EmotionOptions, SentimentOptions
```

and

```
   response = nlu.analyze(text=data,features=[nluFeatures.Keywords(),nluFeatures.Entities(),nluFeatures.Categories(),nluFeatures.Emotion(),nluFeatures.Sentiment()])
```

would become

```
   response = nlu.analyze(text=data,features=Features(keywords=KeywordsOptions(),entities=EntitiesOptions(),categories=CategoriesOptions(),emotion=EmotionOptions(),sentiment=SentimentOptions()))
```